# Getting error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, html, download

I got an Unique Download Link Generator from: [here](https://ardamis.com/2008/06/11/protecting-a-download-using-a-unique-url/) and started to set it up on my server, but if I try to open the `download.php`, I get the error:

> Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in `filepath`
>   on line 18.

The Problem is, that the code was made for PHP5 but I'm using PHP7 so there are some changes between the versions and I'm not able to find them and fix the problem.

My Code:

```
<?php

// Set the maximum number of downloads
$maxdownloads = "2";
// Set the key's viable duration in seconds (86400 seconds = 24 hours)
$maxtime = "86400";

require ('dbconnect.php');

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $id = stripslashes($_GET['id']);
}else{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

// Get the key, timestamp, and number of downloads from the database
$query = sprintf($link, "SELECT * FROM downloadkey WHERE uniqueid=  '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id));
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!$row) { 
    echo "The download key you are using is invalid.";
}else{
    $timecheck = date('U') - $row['timestamp'];

    if ($timecheck >= $maxtime) {
        echo "This key has expired (exceeded time allotted).<br />";
    }else{
        $downloads = $row['downloads'];
        $downloads += 1;
        if ($downloads > $maxdownloads) {
            echo "This key has expired (exceeded allowed downloads).<br />";
        }else{
            $sql = sprintf("UPDATE downloadkey SET downloads = '".$downloads."' WHERE uniqueid= '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($id, $link));
            $incrementdownloads = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

// Debug        echo "Key validated.";

// Force the browser to start the download automatically

/*
Variables: 
    $file = real name of actual download file on the server
    $filename = new name of local download file - this is what the visitor's        file will actually be called when he/she saves it
*/

 ob_start();
 $mm_type="document/text";
 $file = "text.txt";
 $filename = "text.txt";

 header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
 header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

 ob_end_clean();
 readfile($file);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes it did solve the problem, again thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems in your code. Firstly, on this line:

```
$query = sprintf($link, "SELECT * FROM downloadkey WHERE uniqueid=  '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id));
```

`$link` should not be an input to `sprintf`. This is what is causing the error message that you are seeing. Change it to:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM downloadkey WHERE uniqueid=  '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id));
```

Also, on this line:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE downloadkey SET downloads = '".$downloads."' WHERE uniqueid= '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($id, $link));
```

the order of parameters to `mysqli_real_escape_string` is incorrect (it should be `$link, $id`), so change that line to:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE downloadkey SET downloads = '".$downloads."' WHERE uniqueid= '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id));
```

You also need to change this line:

```
$incrementdownloads = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

to

```
$incrementdownloads = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed them in my code but now I get these errors:** Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\www\download\download.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in E:\www\download\download.php on line 19**